# Python Join a list of integers

Tags: python

I am trying to get list of numbers from:

```
numbers= 1,2
```

to:

```
'1','2'
```

I tried `",".join(str(n) for n in numbers)` but it wont give the targeted format.

Comment: This is unclear. Do you want that output as a string or list/tuple?

Comment: What you describe isn't anything like "joining".

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
>>> numbers = 1,2
>>> print ",".join("'{0}'".format(n) for n in numbers)
'1','2'
```

Answer (score 91):

How about that?

```
>>> numbers=1,2
>>> numbers
(1, 2)
>>> map(str, numbers)
['1', '2']
>>> ",".join(map(str, numbers))
'1,2'
```

Answer (score 10):

Use this:

```
>>> numbers = [1, 2]
>>> ",".join(repr(str(n)) for n in numbers)
'1','2'
```

Comment: imo my solution is more explicit which is why I don't really like this method.

Answer (score 9):

What does your answer give?

```
>>> print ",".join(str(n) for n in numbers) 
1,2
```

If you really want `'1','2'` then do

```
>>> print ",".join("'%d'" % n for n in numbers)
'1','2'
```

Comment: I hope you don't take this the wrong way, but you have a lovely chicken.

Answer (score 1):

By me the easiest way is this... Let's say you got list of numbers:

```
nums = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Then you just convert them to list of strings in a single line by iterating them like this:

```
str_nums = [str(x) for x in nums]
```

Now you have list of strings and you can use them as a list or join them into string:

```
",".join(str_nums)
```

Easy :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bit of a hack. Not *that* hacky though, it's unlikely to bit-rot because JSON is so common.

```
import json
numbers = [1,2,3]
json.dumps(numbers, separators=(",",":"))[1:-1]
'1,2,3'
```

If you are ok with some whitespace, you can shorten it to

```
import json
numbers = [1,2,3]
json.dumps(numbers)[1:-1]
'1, 2, 3'
```